# XML import to PostgreSQL using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, import, nokogiri

I would like to import an XML file from a URL using Nokogiri and save it to my PostgreSQL database.

In my schema.rb I have the following table:

```
create_table "centres", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.string   "c_type"
  t.text     "description"
  t.float    "lat"
  t.float    "long"
  t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
end
```

Below is a sample from the file I am importing:

```
<facility>
<id>CG432</id>
<facility_name>Cairncry Community Centre</facility_name>
<expiration>2099-12-31T23:59:59Z</expiration>
<type>Community Centre</type>
<brief_description/>
<lat>57.1601027</lat>
<long>-2.1441739</long>
</facility>
```

I created the following import.rake task in lib/tasks:

```
require 'rake' 
require 'open-uri'
require 'Nokogiri'

namespace :db do 
    task :xml_parser => :environment do 
        doc = Nokogiri::XML(open("http://sample.xml")) 
        doc.css('centre').each do |node| 
                facility_name = node.xpath("centre").text,
                type = node.xpath("centre").text,
                brief_description = node.xpath("centre").text,
                lat = node.xpath("centre").text,
                long = node.xpath("centre").text,               

                Centre.create(:facility_name => name, :type => c_type, :brief_description => description, :lat => lat, :long => long)
            end
        end
    end
```

I tried `rake db:migrate` and also `rake -T | grep import`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XML does not contain a `<centre>` element. Also there is no need to create a bunch of variables if you only intend to use them once.

```
doc.css('facility').each do |f|
  centre = Centre.create do |c|
    c.facility_name = node.css("facility_name").first.text
    c.type = node.css("type").first.text
    c.brief_description = node.css("brief_description").first.text
    c.lat = node.css("lat").first.text
    c.long = node.css("long").first.text
  end
end
```

A more elegant way to do this if the selectors match up with your attributes is:

```
KEYS = ["facility_name", "type", "brief_description", "lat", "long"]
doc.css('facility').each do |f|
  values = KEYS.map { |k| node.css(k).first.text }
  Centre.create(Hash[*KEYS.zip(values).flatten])
end
```

An explaination on how this works can be found at: http://andywenk.github.io/programming/2014/06/27/ruby-create-a-hash-from-arrays/

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the link!

Comment: Just to add, there was one more mistake I had in my original code - require 'Nokogiri'. When I tried to push to Heroku and run migrations it would always abort the rake. After some research I found that nokogiri is not supposed to be capitalized. After I changed that it worked great.